# NLUA bad image exception in x64 .Net core

Tags: .net, lua, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, nlua

I use NLUA dll in my visual studio 2017 on windows 10 , I am using .Net core 2.1 x64 to build and publish my ASP.Net core Application .

Bad Image exception 'bad image KeraLua.NativeMethods.LuaLNewState()' is recieved when i try to do 
    MyLua = new NLUA.Lua()

I use latest NLUA 1.3.2 .

The problem is that when i delete my .Netcore x64 and use x32 , it works perfectly !

I am obligated to use .Netcore x64 but it isn't working .
Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: solution is to rebuild the code as x86 from github and don't use the x86-x64 dlls in NuGet Manager , that way it works for me

Comment: Please re-test the https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLua/ and see if works for you.